# Azure Cosmos DB - How to bring the Primary Region Offline and force Automatic failover?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have provisioned Cosmos DB with the following configurations

1. West US - Primary => Read & Write
2. East US - Secondary => Read

[image]

I want to prove that when the primary goes offline the secondary will become the primary and function.

I could successfully perform the manual failover however I don't know how to take the primary database offline (Note: I could delete only the secondary replica)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot take a region "offline" and removing the region is not possible while it is functioning at the primary write region. If you want to test failover, use the manual failover. This is sufficient for BCDR testing scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Juts a supplementary here. As @MarkBrown indicated, you can use manual failover, and this is an [official document for it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-database-account#manual-failover)